# Is there a case when (c===c) is false?

Tags: javascript

I saw the other day this riddle:

Having the following JavaScript code:

```
var c;

// YOU CAN NOT CHANGE THE FOLLOWING CODE
if (c===c) {
    alert ("YOU LOSE!");
}
else {
    alert ("YOU WIN!");
}
```

By changing only the c value (before if-statement) you have to make the code display the “YOU WIN!” message.

Is that really possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's possible.

```
var c = NaN;
```

Answer (score 4):

`NaN` is not equal to itself.

```
console.log(NaN === NaN);
```

**Output**

```
false
```

Quoting from the [`NaN's MDN docs`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN#Testing_against_NaN)

> Equality operator (== and ===) cannot be used to test a value against
>   NaN. Use Number.isNaN() or isNaN() instead.

```
NaN === NaN;        // false
Number.NaN === NaN; // false
isNaN(NaN);         // true
isNaN(Number.NaN);  // true
```